# Understanding the replica island rendering system. Why does it have a double-buffer of render commands?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl-es, renderer

I made a relatively simple structured Android game that could quite easily get away with updating the game logic and doing the rendering all inside the onDrawFrame function in the render thread of the GLSurfaceView. However, thinking of future projects I have begun to explore multi-threaded options, including running the main game update logic outside of the rendering thread, which is what replica island did. There is a blogpost about it here: http://replicaisland.blogspot.co.nz/2009/10/rendering-with-two-threads.html

Resources such as the replica island source code (https://code.google.com/archive/p/replicaisland/source) have been helpful in understanding this double-buffered render-command-registering multi-threaded renderer idea. The game loop updates objects and those that want to be drawn register themselves in the not-currently-being-used buffer. That buffer gets swapped at some point and the renderer works on those render-commands to draw them using opengl.

There are some things I am not really understanding yet.

The replica island game thread loop (GameThread.java) starts with a block waiting for the renderer to stop rendering (mRenderer.waitDrawingComplete) . It then updates the game logic, and then swaps the buffers. Swapping the buffers notifies the renderer to start on the next batch. When the renderer is done the game loop will update again, and so on.
This approach doesn't seem to run the game logic and the code that loops over the render objects in parallel? They seem to operate in lock-step, and derive their performance boost from the game logic not having to block while opengl actually finishes the rendering after the onDrawFrame function is finished.

I tested similar code and this is definitely faster than just single-threading it all when there is a large amount of stuff to be drawn. However, because the render loop does not loop over objects while the game thread is also working with them, there doesn't seem to be any inherent need to have the multiple render command buffers. From what I can read of it (and I am guessing I am mistaken somewhere) the game update is not actually updating the 2nd buffer while the renderer is using the first. If that is the case then why have two buffers at all?

Why is the game thread waiting for the renderer to stop drawing before it does its update?

Answer (score 0):

Doom 3 does the same thing: process all of app input and events, then [kick off a separate thread](https://github.com/logangorence/DOOM-3-BFG/blob/master/neo/framework/common_frame.cpp#L772) to run and draw the next frame while submitting the previous frame to the render system.  Then, it waits for the [Game Thread to return](https://github.com/logangorence/DOOM-3-BFG/blob/master/neo/framework/common_frame.cpp#L796) before swapping the buffers.

Both Threads are designed to use a specific buffer frame, the `render` or the `draw` frame.  Because they are confined to a specific buffer **you don't need to use mutexes or synchronization primitives to control access**.  Waiting on the thread *is* the synchronization.

It also keeps rendering and drawing in sync.  You are already rendering a frame behind, and want to keep the lag to a minimum. Only drawing a single frame ahead means that your interpolation code is closer to elapsed time and only needs to emit render commands once per render frame. (As opposed to constantly blasting out frames and letting the render thread drop/skip).

> Why is the game thread waiting for the renderer to stop drawing before it does its update?

The render system is a state machine, one that you can't concurrently execute commands against.  Draw emits render commands that can be executed asynchronously on the other thread.  Draw sends them and forgets.  It doesn't care about the state or what happens to them.  This is async.

Switching the window mode from fullscreen to windowed, changing surface resolutions or generally any other render state update needs to fully execute before continuing (synchronous or blocking) and must be performed with a know API state.  These and other updates might affect Draw states, window states, etc...

So the wisdom is to perform event processing and update() on a single synchronized thread so we can block when we need to and change anything that affects states (**any state**).  Then split off and issue render commands on the `draw` thread and execute the previous set on the `render` thread.

Comment: This breakdown of the quake3 engine describes the process I think: http://fabiensanglard.net/quake3/renderer.php, which makes sense. However the replica island game thread blocks at the start of its loop - https://github.com/jimulabs/replica-island-gradle/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/replica/replicaisland/GameThread.java#L54 and also when it swaps buffers. Why does it do both? Isn't that preventing it filling the 2nd buffer while the renderer uses the first?

Comment: The 2nd blocking when he swaps the buffers has another effect: it starts rendering the next frame.  Without the first `wait` you wouldn't have any sections of the game loop where you could safely make modifications to the renderer.  Why at the beginning?  The loop is continuous, he could have put it at the end.  Maybe it just demarks the non-threaded section better.

Comment: Does that not mean that replica island can't make effective use of a 2-buffer system? The quake3 breakdown shows the first buffer getting filled while the render thread is still processing the second buffer and sending data to the GPU, but that can't happen in the replica island code? Because of that first wait, the game thread won't ever start filling buffers until the renderer is no longer busy, which seems to defeat the point of a 2-buffer system? Or am I blind and missing something obvious here.